# Provide seamless access to reviewable.io reviews from github

Tags: git, github, version-control, github-codereviews

We have a github repo with a reviewable.io webhook configured. What we are hoping for is that when any new developers are added as a contributor to the repo, they are automatically provided with seamless access to code reviews for this repo in reviewable.io.

Currently when new users attempt to access a reviewable.io code review from a github PR by clicking the purple button:
[image]

they are presented with this screen:

[image]

And the after clicking "grant authorization", they are presented with this screen:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard back from the reviewable.io folks that there's no way around this authorization dialog as long as Reviewable remains an OAuth app.  OAuth authorizations are granted for a whole account, across all organizations it's a member of, so the user must confirm that they're OK with that. It's a security constraint imposed by GitHub with no workarounds.